# python hashlib different hashes for a copied file of the same content

Tags: python, python-2.7

Running python 2.7 and trying to calculate the hash of two different files into variables so I can compare and use in a boolean loop.  To start off I generate content in file1, then I copy file1 to file2 and run against both file1 and file2, I get different hashes with python hashlib, but running powershell get-filehash against the two different filenames I get the same hash (as I expected).

There is no content difference between file1 and file2, just create file1 with content and copy to file2.

```
import sys
import hashlib

goldresulthashVar = None
testresulthashVar = None


def sha256hashcheck1():
    with open( 'goldresult.txt' ,"rb") as f:
        # Read and update hash string value in blocks of 4K
        for byte_block in iter(lambda: f.read(4096),b""):
            sha256_hash.update(byte_block)
        goldresulthashVar = sha256_hash.hexdigest()
        print goldresulthashVar

def sha256hashcheck2():
    with open( 'test.txt' ,"rb") as f2:
        # Read and update hash string value in blocks of 4K
        for byte_block in iter(lambda: f2.read(4096),b""):
            sha256_hash.update(byte_block)
        testresulthashVar = sha256_hash.hexdigest()
        print testresulthashVar     

sha256hashcheck1()
sha256hashcheck2()
```

Any pointers or suggestions?

Comment: What is this `sha256_hash`? If you call consecutive `update(a)` and `update(b)` you just doing `update(a+b)` https://docs.python.org/3/library/hashlib.html#hashlib.hash.update. Try `hashlib.sha256(byte_block).hexdigest()`

Comment: Sorry - missed one var declare when I pasted my script, also doing: sha256_hash = hashlib.sha256() as a declared var at the start of the script ... reading through your hashlib citation now, ty

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Verified the size of the text files my script was intending to hash and switched to a small single file read with no update per Andrej's pointe to the docs.

```
def sha256hashcheck1():
    with open( 'goldresult.txt' ,"rb") as f:
        bytes = f.read() # read entire file as bytes
        goldresulthashVar = hashlib.sha256(bytes).hexdigest();
        print(goldresulthashVar)
```

Getting good confirm able hashes across multiple files now.